# Do I need a game loop?

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginning developer for android, and I'm just trying to make a simple clicker game. Lets just say I've got one screen. It's got a text view for a counter, a button to increase the counter, a passive increase to that counter, and a button to increase the passive. I don't need any animation. I'm not quite sure what the best way to implement this is. Do I make a game loop using a thread? I tried doing some googling for this, but I couldn't really find anything relevant. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish most of your game with Activities and function calls. Your game sounds very linear, which I would say is a good thing for a starting project.

This would be your main code that checks when the button is pressed.

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // Perform action on click.
    }
});
```

If you are going to be passively increasing counters then you could use a handler.

```
TextView textView;
Handler handler = new Handler();  
int count = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    handler.post(updateTextRunnable);
}

Runnable updateTextRunnable = new Runnable()
{  
    public void run() 
    {  
       count++;
       textView.setText("Updating variable: " + count);
       handler.postDelayed(this, TIME_DELAY);  
    }  
};
```

Comment: But what about for passively increasing the counter? Like per second or something like that. Wouldn't that require a loop somewhere?

Comment: I missed that, you are right. I edited my answer with what you need.

Comment: So essentially the runnable just continues to execute as long as the app is up? Awesome. That is exactly the example I needed. Thank you so much!